# How to reverse "disable check in this file only" in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on an Android application in ADT(Eclipse IDE with Android Developer Tool plugin).
I was not able to build it because one of my Java files was giving me errors. I excluded the file from the build path since it was not being used, and I needed it only as a backup. But Eclipse still showed me the build error.

For ignoring this error, I use one of Eclipse's suggested solution - "Disable check in this file only", which worked.

So my question is, How do I reverse this option? Can I re-enable the checking so that it shows the error?

**[EDIT] :** If i rename the file, the error does show up. If i copy the java file into another package also, the error does show up in it's new location. But the existing file just does not show the error. There has to be something like an ANT exclusion list somewhere, where i can remove this filename.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse worked for me.

Comment: Hmmm..That did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it was an Android Lint problem you suppressed - Java problems cannot be removed that way.

You can re-enable it by editing `lint.xml` at the root of your project and removing the relevant

```
<ignore path="..." />
```

rules there.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. I did not even notice the new lint.xml that got generated. Unfortunately even after removing the <ignore> line, the error does not show. I tried restarting eclipse and including the file in the build path as well, but to no avail. I deleted the lint.xml file itself, but still the same.

Comment: Lint only gets automatically run on files you save. You can manually invoke it from the Android Tools menu.

Comment: I do not see any Android Tools menu. I do see a "Window -> Run Android Lint -> " But the submenu is blank, so i cannot run it. Anyway the problem seems to have resolved automatically after an hour. I am guessing some kind of caching issue.

Comment: I just realized the reason i did not see the Lint.xml file earlier is because the project explorer needs to be refreshed manually for it to appear after it has been generated.